# Why google reports it as an error?

Tags: google-search-console

Good morning

In .htaccess I entered the following code:
ErrorDocument 404 (my domain)error404/error-404-pagina-non-trovata.html
ErrorDocument 403 (my domain)error404/error-404-pagina-non-trovata.html

I did not insert the html into the sitemap

Why google reports it as an error?

this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73po.jpg

Thanks to everyone for the answer

Comment: What was the error reported?

Comment: Error 404 page not found https://i.stack.imgur.com/D73po.jpg